# Comparing chars in String elements of an arraylist causing indexoutofboundsexception

Tags: java, arraylist

I am supposed to compare the characters in an arraylist(String) and then if all the Strings have common characters or character or no common character, i have to display the number of common characters in all the strings of an arraylist.
Here is my function:

```
public void theElementor(ArrayList<String> x) {
    char a;
    ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= x.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = x.size()-1; j > i; j--) {
                for (int l = 0; l < x.get(j).length(); l++) { \\error here
                    if (x.get(i).contains(
                            Character.toString(x.get(j).charAt(l)))) {
                        a = x.get(j).charAt(l);
                    store.add(Character.toString(a));
                    }

            }
        }
    }
    for (String element : store) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

I have figured out that much and i am no longer getting the error i was getting earlier, but still not able to get the char or chars common in all the strings i input.

Comment: If `int j = x.size()` then `x.get(j)` will produce an error.  You need to start with size - 1.

Comment: This line is a bit weird: `x.remove(j).charAt(l);`.  Why do you do `charAt` on the entry you just removed, then not use the value?

Comment: @HotLicks i just tried it as well, now i am getting same error when the third loop runs and if statement holds true.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you, i got that, i am uploading the modified code, still error at the third for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try such pattern:

- store all characters in set
- iterate over set and print characters
  that are common for all strings

sample code (if I understand you properly)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add("abcdef");
    x.add("bcdefg");
    x.add("bbccff");

    Set<Character> all = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (String s : x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            all.add(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    for (Character c : all) {
        if (charIsCommon(c, x)) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * return true only if each string in [list] contains character [c]
 */
private static boolean charIsCommon(char c, List<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I should be able to input my own strings and they can be of variable length as well.

Comment: Thank you! this worked fine, but can you expatiate what you did?? I am not fully able to understand how this worked.

Comment: First, this reads all characters from all strings and add **each** character to set. After this our set stores 7 elements {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} - try: `System.out.println(all)`. Second, we iterate over our set (c is current element from set) and check if char c exists in **each** string in x ArrayList. To do this we have izolated method - charIsCommon(c,x). This method iterates thru all strings in list passed as argument and return true if, and only if, all strings have contains that char. See String.indexOf method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, valid indexes of a list range from `0` through `size() - 1`, not `size()`.  The error's cause is your `i` and `j` `for` loops.  Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = x.size(); j > i; j--) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {            // <= becomes <
    for (int j = x.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {    // x.size() becomes x.size() - 1
```

Comment: He was intentionally indexing backwards so he could do `remove`.  Your scheme would break that.

Comment: tried it, now I am getting the same error when the if statement holds true.

Comment: @HotLicks How does my correction stop the indexing backwards?  The `j` `for` loop still starts at the end; the initial value of `j` was corrected to `x.size() - 1`.